# Google fonts not showing in Firefox

Tags: firefox, google-font-api

I'm creating a HTML template. I've attached the google fonts' link to the header of HTML file , It's showing okay in Chrome, But Firefox showing the Arial font instead. Firefox not taking the google fonts.

I'm using this link for font:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cuprum' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

and the simple CSS

```
  font-family: 'Cuprum', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the code?

Comment: Share information about the font

Comment: Is your site http, https, or a local site (file:)?